# Which preposition should I use here:You are not listening! What are you thinking __?

Tags: grammar, prepositions

Which preposition should I use here:You are not listening! What are you thinking __ ?

can i use thinking for?

Comment: Only "of" or "about".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are three valid answers that I can think of (see what I did there?)

> What are you thinking? [ie, no preposition needed at all]
>
> What are you thinking of?
>
> What are you thinking about?

If you said "What are you thinking for?" it would mean the same as 'Why are you thinking?/For what reason are you thinking?', which does not make sense in the context of the previous sentence.

Comment: Nice answer. You might add that *of* is likely to have two possible understood meanings: something like "How could you? What makes you think you don't need to pay attention?" or the same as "What were you thinking about?". Do you agree? And "What are you thinking?" as well. I'm not totally sure on this. Also, I think "What were you thinking about?" and "What are you of?" would be much more common than the other two, seems to me.